# Strange behaviour of macros C/C++

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor, pi

I'm using some macros, and observing some strange behaviour.

I've defined PI as a constant, and then used it in macros to convert degrees to radians and radians to degrees. Degrees to radians works fine, but radians to degrees does not:

piTest.cpp:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define PI atan(1) * 4
#define radians(deg)  deg * PI / 180
#define degrees(rad)  rad * 180 / PI

int main()
{
  cout << "pi: " << PI << endl;
  cout << "PI, in degrees: " << degrees(PI) << endl;
  cout << "45 degrees, in rad: " << radians(45) << endl;
  cout << "PI * 180 / PI: " << (PI * 180 / PI) << endl;
  cout << "3.14159 * 180 / 3.14159: " << (3.14159 * 180 / 3.14159) << endl;
  cout << "PI * 180 / 3.14159: " << (PI * 180 / 3.14159) << endl;
  cout << "3.14159 * 180 / PI: " << (3.14159 * 180 / PI) << endl;

  return 0;

}
```

When I compile and run, I get the following output:

```
pi: 3.14159
PI, in degrees: 2880
45 degrees, in rad: 0.785398
PI * 180 / PI: 2880
3.14159 * 180 / 3.14159: 180
PI * 180 / 3.14159: 180
3.14159 * 180 / PI: 2880
```

It seems like my constant PI works in the numerator, but not the denominator. I've observed the same behaviour in C. I'm running gcc version 4.6.3

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this behaviour?

Comment: Note that with `<cmath>` you should have `M_PI` which is a literal constant. Your code will actually call `atan` every time you use π, which could slow things down a lot.

Comment: `#define PI 3.14159265359`

Comment: I see nothing gcc-specific here.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - there is no `M_PI` in standard C or standard C++.

Comment: @PeteBecker Indeed, I've even been told it's prohibited by the Standard. Nevertheless, it's omnipresent even on wacky embedded systems. Apparently it's part of the POSIX "X/Open Systems Interfaces" extension.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Macros are (relatively simple) textual substitutions.

Use parentheses in your definitions (both to enclose the macro itself and the macro arguments):

```
#define PI (atan(1) * 4)
#define radians(deg)  ((deg) * PI / 180)
#define degrees(rad)  ((rad) * 180 / PI)
```

Comment: This is only one reason why macros are not a good idea.  With the `constexpr` keyword, many macros can be replaced, allowing for safer typesafe code.

Comment: Another alternative is to replace the macros with `inline` functions.  The functions provide more type safety than textual substitution.  Also consider using **180.0**, noting the decimal point, otherwise the compiler may interpret the macro as integral division not floating point.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't worried about that (integer division) because PI was a double already.

Answer (score 6):

First, `cmath` defines `M_PI`, use that.

Second, cpp macros do textual substitution. Which mean that this:

```
#define PI atan(1) * 4
a = 1 / PI;
```

will be turned into this:

```
a = 1 / atan(1) * 4;
```

before the c/c++ compiler gets a chance to see your code, and it will treat it equivalent to this:

```
a = (1 / atan(1)) * 4;
```

which is not what you want.

Your define should look like this:

```
#define PI (atan(1) * 4)
```

and everything should be fine.

This is not really strange behaviour, but well documented behaviour of the c-preprocessor.

You should search the web for other pitfalls with macros. (hint: parameter passing)

Comment: `M_PI` is an extension, not a standard C or C++ part of `<math.h>` or <cmath>`, so one should not rely on it being defined when writing standard code. Even implementations that define it in some circumstances (as when POSIX support is requested) may omit it in others (when compiling in strict modes).

Comment: @EricPostpischil, hmm.. always assumed it was standard. But I'll keep using it, to lazy to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I was aware of M_PI, but I had read somewhere that you had to  was that it required using #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES (I guess this is just a Visual C++ thing), and I was worried there might be something defined in there that might mess with something else in my code. Since I only needed pi, I figured I'd just define it myself.

Answer (score 2):

You should use parenthesis for your macros to specify precedence.  In addition to that, i think in many cases math.h will define PI for you

Answer (score 2):

Macros just do text substitution without regard for context, so what you wind up with is:

```
cout << "PI, in degrees: " << atan(1) * 4 * 180 / atan(1) * 4 << endl;
```

Note the distinct lack of parens around the second `atan(1) * 4`, causing it to divide only by `atan(1)` and then multiply by 4.

Instead, use inline functions and globals:

```
const double PI = atan(1) * 4;
double radians(double deg) { return deg * PI / 180; }
double degrees(double rad) { return rad * 180 / PI; }
```

Comment: If using C++11, use `constexpr` to allow this to be used in a compile time manner.  I.e. `constexpr double radians(double deg) { return deg * PI / 180; }` could be evaluated in the compiler rather than the runtime environment.

Comment: Inadvertently left out the `inline` keyword.

Comment: I'm not using C++11. Macros are faster than inline functions, aren't they? I don't think the speedup would be noticeable in my case anyway, just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Also good practice: Add brackets around all your parameters:

```
#define radians(deg)  ((deg) * PI / 180)
```

because the expression you pass as parameter might include operators, too.

Or even better: Use (inline-) functions instead of macros, to avoid surprises with sideeffects when a parameter is evaluated multiple times like here:

```
#define sqr(x)  ((x) * (x))
```

The only disadvantage you get with inline functions: You can define them for one type, only (unless you use C++ templates)